# A partition algorithm

Tags: algorithms, arrays, partition-problem

I have encountered the following problem that I found very interesting to solve:

> Given an array of positive integers $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ you are required
>   to partition the array into $3$ blocks/partitions such that the maximum
>   of sums of integers in each partition is the minimum it can be.
>   Restriction: you cannot alter the turn in which the numbers appear
>   (example: if you have $\{2, 5, 80, 1, 200, 80, 8000, 90\}$ one partition
>   **CANNOT** be the $\{2, 80, 1, 90\}$). The program must output **ONLY** the maximum sum, not the partitions.

So, for example let's have the array $\{2, 80, 50, 42, 1, 1, 1, 2\}$. The best partitioning according to the problem is 
$$\{\, \{2, 80\},\, \{50\},\, \{42, 1, 1, 1, 2\} \,\}$$, so the output of the program in this case would be $82$.

I have already thought of a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm, but isn't there any better ( e.g. $\mathcal{O}(n)$ or $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ ) algorithm?

My $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm is (it is pseudocode):

> 1. input $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
> 2. **Let** $m \leftarrow -1$
> 3. **Let** $r_1 \leftarrow  r_2 \leftarrow r_3 \leftarrow  0$
> 4. **Let** $A \leftarrow (a_0,...,a_{n-1})$
> 5. **Let** $S \leftarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{a_i}$
> 6. **for each** $i = 1$ **until** $n-2$ **do**
> 7. $\quad r_1 \leftarrow (r_1 + a_{i-1})$
> 8. $\quad r_2 \leftarrow 0$
> 9. $\quad$ **for each** $j = (i+1)$ **until** $n-1$ **do**
> 10. $\quad\quad r_2 \leftarrow (r_2 + a_{j-1})$
> 11. $\quad\quad r_3 \leftarrow S - (r_2  + r_1)$
> 12. $\quad\quad \max_{\mathsf{temp}} \leftarrow \max(\max(r_1,r_2),r_3)$
> 13. $\quad\quad$**if** $(\max_{\mathsf{temp}} < m \, \vee m = -1)$ **then**
> 14. $\quad\quad\quad  m \leftarrow \max_{\mathsf{temp}}$
> 15. $\quad\quad$**endif**
> 16. **return** $m$

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek [Posted it there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80442/a-partition-algorithm) too but I want a **brand new** algorithm, not someone to check the above

Comment: Please [don't crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) on different SE sites simultaneously! Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration or repost. It may be prudent to include links in either direction and explain why the particular perspective of the other site seems useful.

Comment: What is the value of $a_{-1}$ in your pseudo-code (first iteration of outer loop) ?

Comment: Cross-posted on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/80442/65105) and on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28501751/781723).  [This violates site rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917).  No, cross-posting on 3 sites and then deleting 2 of them later after you get answers is not allowed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you find it interesting to solve, I do not want to completely
spoil it too much  for you. So here is a big hint to solve it in linear time.

You start with two indices $i$ and $j$ which are the first and last indices of
central segment.

Initially you set $i=0$ and $j=n$. And you compute the 3 sums in
$s_1$, $s_2$ and $s_3$. So initially $s_1=s_3=0$.

Then you progressively increase $i$ and decrease $j$, by variations of
1, keeping $s_1$ and $s_3$ about the same value (by doing the change on the
smallest sum $s_1$ or $s_3$), until one becomes bigger than $s_2$.
Each increment or decrement  takes constant time (adding or
substracting the value of an element to two of the sums, and doing a
few comparisons).

When one of $s_1$ and $s_3$ becomes larger than $s_2$, say for example
$s_1$. Then you have $s_1\geq s_2 > s_3$.

Then you know that the right value for $i$ is either the current value
or the previous value. Typically it is the previous value of i, if
$s_1$ has become greater that the previous value of $s_2$. But things
are a bit more subtle. So you note this value of $s_1$ as $m_1$, a
possibility for the maximum, and then try to see if you could have
achieved a lower value for the maximum with the previous value of $i$
and $s_1$,
just before the last increase. So you revert $i$ to that previous
value, and you start to decrease $j$ to get the lowest possible maximum for
$s_2$ and $s_3$ without touching $i$ (that is easy, and recall that $s_1$ remains lower
than both others sums). Let $m_{2,3}$ be the lowest maximum found. Now, if
$m_{2,3}$ is greater than $m_1$, then the answer is $m_1$, else the
answer is $m_{2,3}$.

And you must consider the symmetrical case when $s_3$ is the first to
exceed $s_2$.

Comment: So, we are using a two-pointer approach. Just I didn't much understand the last part: the "fiddling with the limits". Moreover, what to do if somehow we encounter s1==s2 or s3==s2?

Comment: When $s_1$ or $s3$ becomes greater than $s_2$, then you know that the
current values for $i$ and $j$ are nearly optimal. But You then need a
little bit of case analysis to get precisely the best choice for
them. Sometimes, if you have a bunch of very small elements, you may
have to choose where they go. But the algorithm stays linear. I did
not develop all details. This should be faster (about twice as fast)
than the first algorithm given on stackoverflow. I did not read the
second one.

Comment: @Jason I updated the answer. You have it all. It is obviously linear, and
explores only about 2/3rd of indices on average for the boundaries
between partitions. BTW, why the tag `dynamic programming`? - - - - Please clean up by deleting your 2 previous comments.

Comment: I thought it could have a DP solution, but not... So, I cleaned comments and tags up. But can you explain why from the reverted i, there is a need to decrease j? So, the algorithm is approximately 2*n because we have two loops - the normal and for the reverted.

Comment: Actually, constants do not mean much in asymptotic complexity,
i.e. $O(2n)=O(n)$. But, if you want to analyze the loops, you see that
indices are used at most once, by $i$ or by $j$. The second loop looks
at indices not used by the first. So it can count as a single
loop. There is no decrease of sums in the secong loop, but just the
fact that $j$ has to progress by decreasing in both loops. It may be
that you can save some operations on each step with a cumulative sum
array suggested by Jarod42. This would require precise counting. It might be a bit better in average complexity.

Comment: What about test {50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50}? This algorithm (if I programmed it correctly) outputs 90, while the correct result is 110 with partitions { {50, 40}, {30, 20, 10, 20, 30}, {40, 50} }!!!

Comment: And on test {50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50} it outputs 90, while the correct is 120!

Comment: I tested by hand. First test gives $m_1=120$ and $m_{2,3}=110$, so the
answer is $110$.  Second test gives $m_1=120$ and $m_{2,3}=120$, so
the answer is $120$. Hence, I do get the right answer in both cases. I
may have poorly explained, or your transcription is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21143/discussion-between-jason-and-babou).